# Automatic switch to login window after automatic user login on MacOS Sierra

Tags: macos, login, automation

I do need a user to automatically login on startup. I've achieved it as per https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201476

This user performs actions like VPN auto connect in Shimo, but then the machine should be present for others to login.

When that is done, I want that Mac to switch to login window without logging off the user right after the user is logged in.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: this tool might be adaptable to just select the log in window as opposed to logging in the other account somewhat insecurely - http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/accountswitcher/index.html

Comment: You will have to edit that tool if you don't want to use it entirely - it has everything you'd need to script it in AppleScript. Also Automator could probably record a "watch me and repeat these mouse movements" script to log out one user.